# How do Drupal Cron Tasks get activated in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, drupal, cron

In Linux, we use `crontab` to run automations. So far i know only that system cron can make automated tasks. Now i found out Drupal has the Crons also. But, the Drupal whatever is a bundle of script itself only.

I so far realized there is no way to make a PHP script to be up & running itself, without System Cron. And also it should not be.

- So how does Drupal Cron get activated unless their tasks are registered in Linux/System `crontab` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal cron is more of a psuedo-cron. It doesn't utilize the system crontab, or anything like that. Rather, it runs during the bootstrap process.

If your cron is set to 3 hours, for example, the bootstrap process (everytime you visit a Drupal page) will check to see if it's time to run the cron. If the time is >= 3 hours, the cron tasks will run.

This means that the cron runs are dependent on the visits your site gets. If no one is visiting your site, then the cron will not run.

Comment: `that the cron runs are dependent on the visits your site gets. If no one is visiting your site, then the cron will not run.` LoL so the so-called DRUPAL CRON are like that, actually? So it does NOT mean it is exact timed process? So funny!! Fake Crons!! Btw, thanks man.

Comment: No problem. The cron in Drupal 7 comes from a contrib module in Drupal 6 called poor man's cron. https://drupal.org/project/poormanscron

Comment: Right, and that's documented here, by the way: https://www.drupal.org/node/23714 If you want Drupal's cron to behave like an actual cron, just add something like `0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php` to your crontab, and cron will visit your site every hour and perform the cron duties.